# is it possible to split the following string using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, qregexp

suppose I have a string:

```
QString str={time:123,age:{aaa:123,bbb:456},address:aaa,hight:{zzz:111,ccc:{rrr:333,uuu:555},xxx:222}};
```

is it possible using regular expression to split it to

```
str.split(QRegExp(???))
```

==>

```
    time:123  
    age:{aaa:123,bbb:456}  
    address:aaa  
    hight:{zzz:111,ccc:{rrr:333,uuu:555},xxx:222}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to use regexes for this example, but note that they can't deal with arbitrary levels of nesting, so if your real-life examples are more complex than this, you're probably best to use another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it JSON? In that case, use a JSON parser.

In general, use a parser appropriate for the language. This cannot be correctly solved with regular expressions.

Comment: It is JSON, Thanks for your clue!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match levels of nesting, which is not a regular language (and thus regular expressions can't match it).

It shouldn't be too hard to write a simplistic non-regex parser for this, though.

Comment: It's not impossible for recursive regex engines.